# Deserializing data returned single or array

Tags: json.net

I'm using the code from [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-data-from-the-web-and-map-i) and it works beautifully well at deserializing json to classes.

While this works wonderfully with single objects, when I get an array back from the url, this doesn't handle that. I tried adjusting the code to handle an array, but I think the above code is a step above my grade at the moment.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/jeffpatton1971/8823781) I'm trying to get working:

```
public static T[] GetEdmundsContents<T>(string url) where T : new()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var jsonData = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Sleep(1000);
            jsonData = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(jsonData) : new T();
    }
}

static void Sleep(int ms)
{
    new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(ms);
}
```

Here is the JSON I'm getting back from the web service (abbreviated):

```
[
    {
        "authorNames": [
            "Audi Press AG"
        ],
        "captionTranscript": "2013 Audi A6 3.0T Premium quattro Sedan Cargo Area",
        "type": "PHOTOS",
        "subType": "interior",
        "shotTypeAbbreviation": "CARGO",
        "photoSrcs": [
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_150.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_87.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_131.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_423.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_396.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_175.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_500.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_600.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_1600.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_400.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_2048.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_98.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_276.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_300.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_815.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_717.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_196.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_cargo_oem_1_185.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "authorNames": [
            "Audi Press AG"
        ],
        "captionTranscript": "2013 Audi A6 3.0T Premium quattro Sedan Interior",
        "type": "PHOTOS",
        "subType": "interior",
        "shotTypeAbbreviation": "I",
        "photoSrcs": [
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_396.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_196.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_276.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_185.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_175.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_300.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_500.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_423.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_131.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_150.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_600.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_2048.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_87.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_717.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_1600.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_400.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_98.jpg",
            "/audi/a6/2013/oem/2013_audi_a6_sedan_30t-premium-quattro_i_oem_2_815.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please post the actual JSON that you are having trouble with, and the code that you are attempting to use to deserialize it.  Then we can help fix it.  The example you linked to doesn't show us what YOU are doing.

Comment: @BrianRogers I've added the code, it's more or less identical to my original link. I've also included what I tried to do to make it go.

Comment: OK, but what is T and what is your JSON (when you get an array back)?

Comment: T defined (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: @BrianRogers There is a limit on what I can paste into a comment, so above is a shortened return. I don't think the json is too mangled, the actual return has about a dozen photo "objects"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't that far off. The only problem is this line:

```
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData) 
    ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(jsonData) 
    : new T();
```

It should be this:

```
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData) 
    ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(jsonData) 
    : new T[]();
```

If you prefer you can use `List<T>` instead of `T[]` and it should work just as well.  The full method would then look like the following (note I removed the try/catch block since you aren't doing anything with the caught exception -- no need to catch if you're just going to rethrow):

```
public static List<T> GetEdmundsContents<T>(string url) where T : new()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        string jsonData = client.DownloadString(url);
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData) 
            ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonData) 
            : new List<T>();
    }
}
```

For the JSON you posted, `T` should be a class like this:

```
class CarSpec
{
    public List<string> authorNames { get; set; }
    public string captionTranscript { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string subType { get; set; }
    public string shotTypeAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public List<string> photoSrcs { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can call your method like this:

```
List<CarSpec> specs = GetEdmundsContents<List<CarSpec>>(url);
```

Comment: The class I get when I paste in the json is a little different.
public class Class1
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
    public string[] authorNames { get; set; }
    public string captionTranscript { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string subType { get; set; }
    public string shotTypeAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public string[] photoSrcs { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Paste where?  I used [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/), then renamed the `RootObject` class to `CarSpec` to get what you see in my answer.  Since the API is returning an array, you need to deserialize to a list (or array) of that class.  The alternative structure you have in your comment won't compile because your outer class name (`Class1`) has the same name as one of the inner classes.

Comment: Assuming you correct the name of the inner class, if you deserialize to your `RootObject` it still won't work because the data class (the inner `Class1`) is one level down from the root.  In other words, the structure doesn't match the JSON.  You'd need to deserialize to a list of the inner `Class1` to make it work.  Which is essentially the same as what I have in my answer.  (The difference is that you are using arrays for the `authorNames` and `photoSrcs`, while I'm using lists, but that is inconsequential).